# Can you run an air purifier inside a tent to mitigate the bad air quality from remote wildfires?

Tags: tents, forest-fires, air

In my area, the air quality fluctuates due to remote wildfires which are currently burning. For example, the air quality might be unhealthy in the morning but completely normal in the afternoon and evening. I'm told this will keep happening all summer.

Rather than lose the ability to get outdoors this summer, I am thinking of getting a cabin-style tent, setting it up nicely inside, and just staying in the tent when the air quality is bad, going out when it is good. But this plan depends on an air purifier inside the tent (campsite has power) being able to keep up with the airflow into the tent.

Does anyone know if this is a workable idea? Can an air purifier keep up? Is there a specific kind of tent that is best suited to this?

Comment: This UK site [Best Air Purifier for Cleaning Up Your Campervan](https://campingsecrets.co.uk/best-air-purifier/) discusses air purifiers for campervans and caravans. Perhaps there is a lead to something suitable for you.

Comment: Are air purifiers even suitable to remove the dangerous parts of smoke from the air? They certainly won't help against Carbon monoxide or Carbon dioxide poisoning.

Comment: @PMF carbon monoxide is produced by partial combustion in a confined space. Very little would be produced by a free-burning open fire: it would burn into carbon dioxide. And carbon dioxide isn't poisonous: it is toxic only because you might be deprived of enough oxygen, and that too is only likely to happen in a confined space. If OP is camping the actual fires won't be close enough for these to be a concern: I don't suppose the tent is forest fire proof :)